# Can not access phpmyadmin

Tags: wamp

I have installed fresh copy of wampserver. Normally, at the very first beginning of phpadmin comes as without username and password. If only user prefer he can create a login.

Problem is after the installation I tried to go to phpadmin. However, it asks for credentials.

I am confused about this? Is there any default credential for wamp server? How log in to phpadmin?

Answer (score 0):

I randomly tried username root and password = "" . It worked.